# How to be informed when gtk.paned slider's position changed?

Tags: c, gtk

I wanna the hpaned to remember the slider position, then I need to catch the event of hpaned's changing slider position. According to official doc, paned only have a few signals, and none of them is about slider's position.

So, is there a event about hpaned's slider? And how to catch it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can connect to "notify::position" signal.

Answer (score 3):

`notify::position` fires multiple times as the slider is moved.

I find `button-release-event` is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the [size-allocate](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-size-allocate) signal of one of the two children of the paned. The signal will be emitted after the slider's position has been changed.

Comment: If the child property "resize" is set to False, then the child will not be resized, hence size-allocate signal will not be emitted.