# How to be informed when gtk.paned slider's position changed? (c#)

Tags: c#, gtk

This is exactly same question as [How to be informed when gtk.paned slider's position changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857255/how-to-be-informed-when-gtk-paned-sliders-position-changed) but in this case it's about GTK#

There is no such notify::position thing.

I've tried following:

```
this.hpaned1.AcceptPosition += new AcceptPositionHandler(Changed);
```

as well as

```
this.hpaned1.ButtonReleaseEvent+= new ButtonReleaseEventHandler(Changed);
```

but neither works :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation [here](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aGLib.Object.AddNotification%28System.String%2cGLib.NotifyHandler%29):

```
this.hpaned1.AddNotification("position", new NotifyHandler(Changed));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `notify::position` is a specific type of the `notify` signal on a GObject. You should still be able to connect to that signal and check if it is for the position.

Comment: but how is it possible to connect to this signal?